# "I watched anime 3 days straight" — what does it mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

When some one says "I watched anime 3 days straight", Does it mean they watched anime for three days sitting in one place *without taking bath, brushing teeth etc.* for three days, or does it mean that they watched anime for three days *including personal grooming, eating etc.* but didn't do any other useful work (like school, office etc.)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**straight** means **in a row**. It conveys the meaning of three entire days spent watching anime, without specifying in particular what is included or not as part of “entire”. I think one can reasonably assume that this means “as a main task”, and it excludes office work or school, as well as other kinds of socialisation (such as parties).

Comment: Although with anime, as with gaming, it may *actually* mean seventy-two continuous hours with fewer breaks than the Guinness Records people would allow for marathon activity and, um, less-than-fastidious hygiene ;o)

Answer (score 4):

To me, that means they didn't do anything else for three days. This means they didn't leave the house, they didn't clean the house, they didn't talk to anyone. They didn't engage in any other unexpected tasks.

I expect that they took bathroom breaks, and they probably had something to eat and drink. These minor things are not considered, because they have to be done. They might have even slept, but probably not, since they added to word "straight". What they are saying is "For three days I watched anime, and did nothing else worthy of being mentioned."

Comment: +1 That's the key phrase: "did nothing else worthy of being mentioned"